# list buttons responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

How can I put this button inline to be responsive? 
had tried doing  but doesnt work.

```
<div class="form-group btn-group"  >
    <ul class="btn-group list-inline social "  style="display: flex;">
      <li class="col-xs-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-default" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In
        </button> 
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="<?=$fbLoginUrl ?>" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook" style="float:left;margin-right:5px, color:#3B5998">Sign in with Facebook </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12">
        <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-social btn-default" style="float:right;">Sign UP Here </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `@media` or sizes using percentages, i.e. `width: 80%`.

Answer (score 1):

You've placed `style="display: flex;"` on your `ul`. By default `flex` containers do not wrap. If you want it to wrap, you need to add

```
flex-wrap:wrap;
```

...to it.

Or, if you only want it to apply on some screen widths, move that declaration in a `CSS` file, where you'll be able to use `@media` queries.

Not being able to add responsiveness rules to it is one of the main reasons inline `style` is considered very bad practice (the other is because it's hard to maintain).

Answer (score 0):

You better use @media queries. Set the @media query based on your target screen. Your button's text is too lengthy as well so it would be best if you display your lists by block to prevent overlapping the screen size.

Mobile View:

```
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
ul.btn-group {
display: block;
}
ul.btn-group li {
display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `style="display: flex;"` from you `ul`tag. Without it the two buttons will be full width (they have the `col-xs-12` class).

To have them in one line in case the modal is displayed larger on larger screens you can add an additional class like `col-sm-6` or `col-md-6` to both.